# crear un listener en 2do plano que se ejecute como servicio de windows

Tags: c#, broadcastreceiver

actualmente necesito crear un listener que haga broadcast sobre la red, y que escuche mensajes provenientes desde cualquier direccuin IP en la red (es una red privada). Actualmente tengo esta funcionalidad implementada en una pagina web a traves de

HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(token => IniciaBroadCast(token));

mi intencion es trasladar esta funcionalidad a un servicio windows, el cual al recibir datos, sea capaz de almacenar estos datos en una tabla en la base de datos instalada en el server.

esto lo necesito, hacer de esta manera, ya que hoy en dia, si el sitio web se cae, los sistemas que envian mensajes a traves de UDP, no pueden enviar sus mensajes.

aca tengo un poco de confusion, porque no entiendo bien que es lo que tengo que especificar en mi servicio windows, el cual ya tengo creado, pero no hace nada.. ya que en el metodo OnStart(), agrego el siguiente codigo

```
        int listenPort = 15000;
        int TiempoEsperaEscucha = 10000;
        timerUp.Interval = TiempoEsperaEscucha;
        StartListener(listenPort);
```

pero al iniciar el servicio, me sale un mensaje que dice que el servicio se inicio y se termino inmediatamente.

Agrego el codigo completo aca, para que quede mas entendible el problema.

el servicio se llama IsAlive()
aca el constructor

```
public IsAlive()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timerUp = new System.Timers.Timer();
        int TiempoEsperaEscucha = 10000;
        timerUp.Interval = TiempoEsperaEscucha;
        timerUp.Elapsed += new  System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timmer_Elapsed);
    }
```

luego en el metodo OnStart()

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        AccuroLog.WriteEntry("Iniciando servicio IsAlive");
        timerUp.Start();

    }
```

y por ultimo, al iniciar el timmer

```
    private void Timmer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.GrabaLog("Inicia Timmer_Elapsed", ArchivoTrace);

        int listenPort = 15000;
        IPEndPoint remoteSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        UdpState state = new UdpState(client, remoteSender);

        client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), state);

        // espera hasta que se pulse una tecla para salir
        //while (1 == 1)
        //{ }
        //Console.ReadKey();
        //client.Close();
        Logger.GrabaLog("termina Timmer_Elapsed", ArchivoTrace);


    }
```

aca  mi problema es que este evento de Timmer_Elapsed, dura solo unos instantes, y se corta con Cliente.Close()..  entonces si llega un mensaje nunca lo voy a recibir.

mi duda es como puedo mantener el puerto en escucha, sin tener que cerrar el proceso...

Comment: es solamente ese el codigo?? o hay mas??

Comment: yo tendria el codigo en un while (1=1) para que se ejecute siempre

Comment: Te recomiendo que mires [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110929/15301) para poder obtener mas información de cual puede ser el problema con tu servicio. Lamentablemente sin mas datos es complicado ayudarte mas.

Comment: el problema, es precisamete que no puedo poner el while (1==1) porque de esa forma el servicio nunca se instala

Answer (score -1):

Buen día, te dejo un ejemplo que yo utilizo para especificar el servicio. Espero y te sirva.

```
public class Service1
{
    Timer tmServicio = null;

    public Service1()
    {
        tmServicio = new Timer();
        tmServicio.Interval = 300000;
        tmServicio.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        tmServicio.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        tmServicio.Stop();
    }

    // Se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo establecido en el timer
     private void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Aqui van las funciones que quieres que realize el servicio de windows
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Gustavo, gracias por tu comentario. en cuanto a tu codigo, te comento que tb lo tengo implementado de esa manera, pero no me sirve, porque lo que necesito, es correr un proceso que cuando detecte un mensaje entrante por un puerto UDP (puerto 15000 por ejemplo) se ejecute una llamada a una funcion.

Comment: en este caso, lo que tengo es un timmer, que cada x segundos, va a levantar un proceso que se llama listener, que se pone a escuchar por el puerto especificado.. pero que dura solo unos segundos, y despues muere, porque nuevamente el timmer despues de X1 segundos, vuelve a levantar el proceso..  en este caso necesito que el proceso se levante solo una vez, en el OnStart, peri que quede a laa escucha en 2do plano. asi, cuando un mensaje llegue por el puerto especificado, se ejecute el proceso.