# ¿Como puedo depurar mi servicio de Windows?

Tags: c#, vb.net

He creado un servicio de Windows en .Net, pero por alguna razón no me funciona. ¿Hay alguna manera de saber que es lo que está fallando y poder depurarlo?

Comment: Esta pregunta/respuesta esta motivada por [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110815/15301)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depurar un Servicio no es tan sencillo como depurar otro tipo de aplicaciones, ya que no se ejecuta en el contexto del Visual Studio. Pero hay varias formas de poder hacerlo:

- **Asociar el depurador al proceso del servicio:**

  1. Compilar el servicio en la configuración de depuración.
  2. Instalar el servicio.
  3. Iniciar el servicio, desde el Administrador de control de servicios, desde el Explorador de servidores o desde el código.
  4. Iniciar Visual Studio con credenciales administrativas, para poder asociarse a los procesos del sistema.
  5. (Opcional) En la barra de menús de Visual Studio, elegir `Herramientas`, `Opciones`. En el cuadro de diálogo `Opciones`, elije `Depuración`, `Símbolos`, activa la casilla `Servidores de símbolos de Microsoft` y, a continuación, elije el botón `Aceptar`.
  6. En la barra de menús, elige `Asociar al proceso` en el menú Depurar o Herramientas. (Teclado: Ctrl+Alt+P)
     Aparecerá el cuadro de diálogo Procesos.
  7. Active la casilla `Mostrar los procesos de todos los usuarios`.
  8. En la sección `Procesos disponibles`, elija el proceso del servicio y, a continuación, seleccione `Asociar`.
     Aparecerá el cuadro de diálogo `Asociar al proceso`.
  9. Elija las opciones apropiadas y, a continuación, elija `Aceptar` para cerrar el cuadro de diálogo.
  10. Establezca los puntos de interrupción que desee usar en el código.
  11. Obtenga acceso al Administrador de control de servicios y manipule el servicio; envíe comandos de detención, pausa y continuación para alcanzar los puntos de interrupción.
- **Ejecutar un servicio de Windows como una aplicación de consola**

  1. Agrega un método al servicio que ejecute los métodos OnStart y OnStop:

     ```
     internal void TestStartupAndStop(string[] args)
     {
         this.OnStart(args);
         Console.ReadLine();
         this.OnStop();
     }
     ```
  2. Vuelve a escribir el método Main como sigue:

     ```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         if (Environment.UserInteractive)
         {
              MyNewService service1 = new MyNewService(args);
              service1.TestStartupAndStop(args);
         }
         else
         {
              // Pon el código que tenías antes aquí
         }
     }
     ```
  3. En la pestaña `Aplicación` de las propiedades del proyecto, establece el Tipo de salida en `Aplicación de consola`.
  4. Elige `Iniciar depuración (F5)`.
  5. Para volver a ejecutar el programa como un servicio de Windows, instálalo e inícialo de la manera habitual para un servicio de Windows. No es necesario invertir estos cambios.
- **Usar [`Debugger.Break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx) o [`Debugger.Launch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx)**

  Este es un método muy sencillo. Simplemente, añade `Debugger.Break` o `Debugger.Launch` en el lugar en el que quieras que la ejecución del servicio se detenga y se lance automáticamente el visual studio con la ejecución detenida en ese punto. A partir de ahí, se puede depurar paso a paso el servicio.
- **Lanzar desde `services.msc`**

  Otra opción es compilar el servicio en modo debug y poner un punto de interrupción donde interese que se lance el depurador. Una vez hecho eso, se debe instalar el servicio para posteriormente lanzarlo desde `services.msc`. En ese momento, el sistema pregruntará si deseas abrirlo con el Visual Studio. Contestando afirmativamente ya se puede depurar el servicio. (*Gracias a @Veelicus*)

---

Añadir por último que depende del error que esté dando el servicio, es posible que podamos encontrarlo en el Log de Eventos del Sistema, y también podríamos capturar las excepciones nosotros mismos y añadirlas a este log o a un log propio. Para mas información sobre como escribir en el Log de Eventos de Windows, podemos consultar [este sitio].(http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/08/writing-to-the-windows-event-log-using-csharp/)

---

*Información obtenida de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx) y [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126016/579895)*

Comment: Yo lo que suelo hacer es compilarlo en modo debug, poner un punto de interrupcion donde interese, instalarlo y lanzarlo desde services.msc, en ese momento te dira si quieres abrirlo con el Visual Studio, lo abres y ya lo puedes depurar.

Comment: @Veelicus es otra opción. La añado al listado :)

Comment: gracias, es la manera mas rapida que conozco, basicamente es como haces tu pero omitiendo algun paso.

Comment: otra opción, en mi opinión clave, es la utilización de logs. Con estos puedes seguir por donde va tu programa. Puedes imprimir variables o puntos por los que vas pasando hasta que sitúas el fallo y con esto no es necesario asociarse al proceso para depurar.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano si,totalmente de acuerdo. Como verás lo explico en la ultima parte de mi respuesta

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que al generar una excepción, ésta puede estar reflejada en el visor de eventos de Windows, hasta ahí estoy de acuerdo. Lo que yo digo es generar los log de tu servicio en un fichero propio, no escribir en los eventos de windows. Con esta herramienta: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial Es muy sencilla de utilizar y puedes usars diferentes niveles de log, archivos circulares para guardar los log...

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano _y también podríamos capturar las excepciones nosotros mismos y añadirlas a este log o a un log propio._

Comment: Buenas @Pikoh, también puedes usar el `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` poniendo alguna condición en el código, por ejemplo, si le pasas al servicio el argumento DEBUG, lo detectas en el código y ejecutas la instrucción.

Comment: Perdona @Pikoh, se me había pasado lo de "o a un log propio", sorry

Comment: @Marc si, `Debugger.Break` y `Debugger.Launch` son similares.(la diferencia tiene que ver mas que nada con que pasa si no existe un debugger apropiado en el sistema). Pero lo añado tambien,gracias :)